# Creating an update package for my custom extension

Tags: magento

So I've made this extension and inside the config.xml I have version 0.1.1 and within magento in the "Create Extension Package" I've given it the version number of 0.1.1 so that the package.xml says version 0.1.1 and it installs just fine.... NOW my problem is is that I've created an update and made it 0.1.2 ... i've changed it in the config.xml and inside the "Create Extension Package" so that the package.xml file says 0.1.2. BUT when I go into the connect manager I get this error

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
'./localpath\\Company\Extension\Helper\Data.php' already exists
```

whats the deal? I'm going to be making updates to my package periodically at some point and some files will be updated that is a given so this should work shouldn't it?

Comment: Its looking like there actually is no solution for this other than to uninstall the extension and re-isntalling it... I should not that I am doing this all through the "Direct package file upload" and not via the store.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea on what to do about this? I have a custom extension I've made and it will obviously have updates... how do i get the updates to install via Magento Connect Manager without getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looking like there actually is no solution for this other than to manually uninstall the extension and re-isntalling it using the "Direct package file upload" option within the Magento Connect Manager...

Looks like I'll just write my own update script for the custom extensions we are building then lol.